# JS Centre-Zeroed Gauge Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, gauge

I've been using Highcharts for a web app I've been building and they've proved great so far. But now I've been tasked to create a gauge for some data that looks like this:

[image: gauge]

And I cannot find any charting library that makes a nice render of a centred zeroed gauge (that fills from the centre to where the needle swings).

Does anyone have any recommendations on libraries or custom implementations?

(P.S. that example gauge that I need to base it on is from a PDF report, so no chance of reverse engineering anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you can play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/remisture/pb70kduv/5/

This is done combining these two:

- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer
- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid

  ```
  $(function () {
   var settings = {
  gaugeMinValue : 0,
  gaugeMaxValue : 8000,
  gaugeStartValue : 3000,
  gaugeStartAngle : -90,
  gaugeEndAngle : 90,
  gaugeUpdateInterval : 500 // ms
  };

  var options = {
  tooltip : {
    enabled : false
  },
  chart : {
    type : 'gauge',
    backgroundColor : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
    plotBackgroundColor : null,
    plotBackgroundImage : null,
    plotBorderWidth : 0,
    plotShadow : false,
    spacing : [5, 30, 5, 30],
    style : {
      fontSize : '1em'
    }
  },

  title : false,

  pane : {
    startAngle : settings.gaugeStartAngle,
    endAngle : settings.gaugeEndAngle,
    background : {
      backgroundColor : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
      borderWidth : 0,
      innerRadius : '60%',
      outerRadius : '100%',
      shape : 'arc'
    }
  },

  plotOptions : {
    gauge : {
      /*dial: {
       radius: 0
       },
       pivot: {
       radius: 0
       },*/
      dataLabels : {
        borderWidth : 0,
        padding : 0,
        verticalAlign : 'middle',
        style : false,
        formatter : function () {
          var output = '<div class="gauge-data">';
          output += '<span class="gauge-value">' + this.y + '</span>';
          output += '</div>';

          return output;
        },
        useHTML : true
      }
    },
    pie : {
      dataLabels : {
        enabled : true,
        distance : -10,
        style : false
      },
      startAngle : settings.gaugeStartAngle,
      endAngle : settings.gaugeEndAngle,
      center : ['50%', '50%'],
      states : {
        hover : {
          enabled : false
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // the value axis
  yAxis : {
    offset : 0,
    min : settings.gaugeMinValue,
    max : settings.gaugeMaxValue,

    title : false,

    minorTickWidth : 0,

    tickPixelInterval : 30,
    tickWidth : 2,
    tickPosition : 'outside',
    tickLength : 14,
    tickColor : '#ccc',
    lineColor : '#ccc',
    labels : {
      distance : 28,
      rotation : "0",
      step : 2,
    },

    plotBands : [{
      thickness : 10,
      outerRadius : "112%",
      from : 0,
      to : 2500,
      color : '#FB8585' // red
    }, {
      thickness : 10,
      outerRadius : "112%",
      from : 2500,
      to : 5500,
      color : '#F9E7AE' // yellow,
    }, {
      thickness : 10,
      outerRadius : "112%",
      from : 5500,
      to : 8000,
      color : '#83DAD9' // green
    }]
  },

  series : [{
    type : 'gauge',
    data : [settings.gaugeStartValue],
  }, {
    type : 'pie',
    innerSize : '87%',
    data : [{
      y : settings.gaugeStartValue,
      name : "",
      color : "#0bbeba"
    }, {
      y : settings.gaugeMaxValue - settings.gaugeStartValue,
      name : '',
      color : "#666666"
    }]
  }],

  navigation : {
    buttonOptions : {
      enabled : false
    }
  },

  credits : false
  };

  $('#gauge1').highcharts(options, buildGraph);

  function buildGraph(chart) {
  if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
    setInterval(function () {
      var gaugePoint = chart.series[0].points[0],
        piePoint = chart.series[1],
        newVal,
        inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 1500);

      newVal = gaugePoint.y + inc;
      if (newVal < settings.gaugeMinValue || newVal > settings.gaugeMaxValue) {
        newVal = gaugePoint.y - inc;
      }

      // Update number gauge value
      gaugePoint.update(newVal);

      // Update pie with current value
      piePoint.points[0].update(newVal);
      piePoint.points[1].update(settings.gaugeMaxValue - newVal);

    }, settings.gaugeUpdateInterval);
    }
    }
    });
  ```